# what use instead of TabsHost Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to use something like tabs not fragment because it's for a mobile app and that controls does not satisfy the requirement, are there something like tabs but with support so not to be deprecated.
any suggestion.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `TabHost` is not deprecated..

Comment: It may be a specification, but why not use a `Fragment`? You could use   a `ViewPager` and Activities can be converted to Fragments very easily too. Unless there is a definite reason to not use `Fragments` though.

Comment: If you are sure that you don't want to use fragments, then ActionBarSherlock (or ActionBar if you are not targeting prev api version)is the way to go.. But what's wrong with tabs with fragments.

Comment: I don't want to use fragment because a I want tabs but on the top and I think fragments is better for tablets so on a movil app will be weird.

Comment: well I've found this and fill my needs

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230862/android-tab-widget-wont-fill-the-width-of-the-screen

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ActionbarSherlock`. You will need to put it as a library or your project

http://actionbarsherlock.com/